# only remove first image in dropzone using this

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

i thought `this` would be referring to the image on click? But I guess `this` is the dropzone itself. So how would i get the image on click then? Right now, when i click an image, it removes the first image on the list. So if I click the last image, that image doesn't get removed, but the first one does.

So in my dropzone options I have this :

```
    'options' => array(
        'init'=> 'js:function() {   
        var url = window.location.href;
        var id = url.substring(url.indexOf("id=") + 3);
//???? this...
        this.on("removedfile", function(event) {
                var id = url.substring(url.indexOf("id=") + 3);
                var name = $(".dz-image-preview").find("a").attr("data-name");
                $.post("/vendor/productImage/RemoveImage",
                {id: id, img: name}).done(function(data) {
                 $(name).remove(data);
                 });
        });
    }'
),
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a string instead of a function to the init option?

Comment: im actually using an extension in yii framework..